# fetch data from table on the basis of condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

> consider my scenario like i have 3 tables 
>   **table1,**
>   **table2,**
>   **table3** i want to fetch some colums from table2 or table3 on the basis of some condition

like

```
select tb1.*, 
if(tb1.status='true' then tb2.name else tb3.name) 
from table1 tb1, table2 tb2, table3 tb3
where tb1.aid=tb2.aid and tb1.aid=tb2.aid
```

in short i want to display some column from either table2 or table3 on the basis of condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT tb1.*,
       CASE WHEN tb1.status = 'true' THEN tb2.name ELSE tb3.name END as `name`
FROM table1 tb1
INNER JOIN table2 tb2 
 ON(t1.aid = tb2.aid)
INNER JOIN table3 tb3
 ON(tb1.aid = tb3.aid)
```

Or with `IF()` like you wanted :

```
SELECT tb1.*,
       IF(tb1.status='true' ,tb2.col1,tb3.col1) as col1,
       IF(tb1.status='true' ,tb2.col2,tb3.col2) as col2,
       IF(tb1.status='true' ,tb2.col3,tb3.col3) as col3
       .....
```

Also, try to avoid the use of implicit join syntax(comma separated) and use the proper syntax of a join, this will help you avoid mistakes like the one you did (compared both conditions to `tb2` instead of one to `tb2` and one to `tb3`

Comment: what to write if i need whole column from table2 SELECT tb1.*,
       IF(tb1.status='true' ,tb2.* ,tb3.name)

Comment: @JunedAnsari You need to add another `IF` for each column . I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
      tb1.*
    , CASE
            WHEN tb1.status = 'true' THEN tb2.name
            ELSE tb3.name
      END AS var_name
FROM table1 tb1
      INNER JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb1.aid = tb2.aid
      INNER JOIN table3 tb3 ON tb2.aid = tb3.aid
```

Use a case expression

BUT, you also need to look hard at how you are joining the tables. There are 2 things to note:

1. stop using comma separated lists of tables, there is a more precise syntax available for joins
2. you currently (in the question) don't have a proper join to table3

Answer (score 1):

if(tb1.status='true',tb2.name,tb3.name) as name

Comment: if i need whole column from table2  like tb2.* and only name from tb.name then?

Comment: maybe as:
`code`
select tb1.*, 
tb2.*
from table1 tb1, table2 tb2
where tb1.aid=tb2.aid and tb1.aid=tb2.aid AND tb1.status='true'
UNION 
select tb1.*, 
tb3.*
from table1 tb1, table3 tb3
where tb1.aid=tb3.aid and tb1.aid=tb3.aid AND tb1.status='false'
`code`